# Using visual studio, why a C++ program cannot run in debug mode while run successfully in release mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio

When I use Visual Studio 2015 to code, i can not debug and run my program in "debug mode", the compile says "debug assertion failed, iterator + offset out of range", however, my program can run successfully in release mode, can also run in other lightweight ide(code :: blocks), what's the reason?

Comment: "Run successfully" != "free of bugs".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behaviour of your code is *undefined*.

You're obviously attempting to index an array (or related container) that is outside its bounds. C++ typically doesn't make any run-time checks for that; it's the job of the programmer to make sure that doesn't happen.

Your debug build is helpfully drawing your attention to that.

The undefined behaviour is manifesting itself differently in the release build.

Fix the assertions!

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to move beyond end() on an iterator most likely. You do not get an error in release mode because the assert statement that checks for this issue is disabled in release mode.